# OnItemClickListener - open new window

Tags: android

How can i open new window (TextView) from ListView by setOnItemClickListener?
I have tried it but it's failed.I have two Xml files (i don't know if i can have 2) and in second Xml file is that TextView. I am trying if i click on any item in ListView it will open new window with TextView.

There is my attempt:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                 TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
                 Uri uriSMSURIs = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
                 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, null, null, null);
                 String bodys = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));        
                 setContentView(R.layout.text);  ----> this is name of second Xml file "Text.xml"
                 message.setText(bodys);

            }

        });
```

Comment: You need to explain how "it's failed".  You should also walk through the code in the debugger or add println statements to tell you whether the callback `onItemClick` got called or not.  Also look in LogCat to see if there are any pertinent error messages or exceptions logged.

Comment: I would also recommend learning Logcat well.  It sounds like you may have seen this coming if you had seen the stack trace from your application crash.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a new window in terms of an AlertDialog, then you should create one by reading this example: [creating AlertDialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)

otherwise if you want to create a new Activity then i would do the following:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {

             Uri uriSMSURIs = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
             Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, null, null, null);
             String bodys = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));        


             Intent textIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TextMessage.class);
             textIntent.putExtra(thisClass.class.getName(),bodys);
             thisClass.this.stratActivity(textIntent); 

        }

    });
```

With this now you can define a new Activity class called TextMessage, which should look something like this:

```
public class TextMessage extends Activity
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   setContentView(R.layout.text);
   TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);

   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String bodys = intnet.getExtras().getString(thisClass.class.getName());
   message.setText(bodys);


 }
```

This should do the trick for you.

p.s. be sure to declare the TextMessage class in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Just putting in my $0.02 that THIS HERE is the method I would truly recommend and was describing in my side note.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the exact failure you're experiencing is, but my guess is something like a NullPointerException due to the order in which you are doing certain operations.  The first thing that I notice is the order of `findViewById()`, `setContentView()`, and `setText()` in your code.

`findViewById()` traverses the currently loaded content view hierarchy, searching for your referenced ID.  So searching for your TextView reference BEFORE you have loaded the correct view hierarchy will produce the wrong result (it will return null unless you had a view in your previous layout with the same ID, in which case you will get the wrong view).  So, upon calling `setText()` you are either setting the text of the wrong view, or no view at all (NullPointerException).

To accomplish your goal, your method should look more like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
    setContentView(R.layout.text);        
    //Search after the layout is inflated and attached
    TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);

    Uri uriSMSURIs = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, null, null, null);
    String bodys = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));        

    message.setText(bodys);
}
```

As a side note, this is the reason Google recommends starting a new Activity (truly more like "opening a new window") for this operation instead of always reloading the content view (like the way Hakan proposed you do things).  People often get confused that when the content view is reset, all their view references are no longer valid.

Hope that helps!  If not, we'd all love more clarification on the exact failure you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at the AlertDialog.Builder and then search for an example of how to build a AlertDialog with an EditText-field.

Answer (score 1):

OK the simple way is to make sure the called activity extends ListActivity.

EG:

```
public Class activity2 extends ListActiivty{

  code goes here
  }
```